# How to install openshift origin client tools v3.11.0? And what is the best (open source)OS for it?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I am having lots of trouble installing openshift okd 3.11. I have started with 3.9 and I could have it installed and started to work on it. However, needing to use kubevirt I need the 3.11 version.
I have only one machine so I want an all-in-one server. ( the oc cluster up tool).

I have done everything in this link : (and a bunch of others)

https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.0/docs/cluster_up_down.md

And in step 4:I did this

```
wget https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v3.11.0/openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit.tar.gz

tar -zvxf openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit

cd openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit

sudo cp oc /usr/local/bin/
```

I have tried these steps on fedora 31 and I got this issue where once I put `oc cluster up` it reaches the sentence below and then I have a timed out

```
Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
```

And I tried it on centOS 7 and I got this error.

```
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
error: unexpected error inspecting image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11
```

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-109.gitcccb291.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      cccb291/1.13.1
 Built:           Tue Mar  3 17:21:24 2020
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-109.gitcccb291.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      cccb291/1.13.1
 Built:           Tue Mar  3 17:21:24 2020
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

I have no idea what to do. 
It's been going on like this for a while.
Can you please help with this issue and let me know the OS and conditions that helped you launch your openshift 3.11.

Comment: You should clarify your question - the header asks about client tools, but eventually you ask for help with the server..

Comment: These 3 free RedHat developer eBooks (just register to RH developers) provide installation details for OpenShift (incl. v3) through different scenarios:
 1. more on the developers' viewpoint to devOps: https://developers.redhat.com/books/openshift-developers-guide-impatient-beginners
 2. more on deployment automation and 12-factor Apps: https://developers.redhat.com/books/devops-openshift-cloud-deployments-made-easy
 3. more on container management: https://developers.redhat.com/books/deploying-openshift